# How to go to a specific tab in Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla, mootools

I have created a component using joomla 1.7 and I have used tabs like follows. Now My active page is First Tab(tab1.php). What I want is I want to go to the third tab by clicking a link. Following link is used to go to this component page, currently it loads last clicked tab. Plz help to solve this.

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_movies&controller=movie&task=allocate" >Allocate</a>

$pane =& JPane::getInstance('tabs', array('startOffset'=>0));
echo $pane->startPane( 'pane' );
echo $pane->startPanel(JText::_('First Tab'), 'panel1' ); 
include_once('tab1.php');    
echo $pane->endPanel();
echo $pane->startPanel(JText::_('Second Tab'), 'panel2' ); 
include_once('tab2.php');    
echo $pane->endPanel();
echo $pane->startPanel(JText::_('Third Tab'), 'panel3' ); 
include_once('tab3.php');    
echo $pane->endPanel();
echo $pane->endPane();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following link which execute some mootool code

```
<a href='#' onClick='$(\"IdOfTabHeader\").fireEvent(\"click\"); return false;'>Click</a>
```

Comment: I used this way `<a href="#" onClick="$('#panel3').fireEvent('click'); return false;" >Allocate</a>` but it didn't work and return error `$("#panel3") is null`

Comment: your right # is not there I removed it and tried but again same result `$("panel3") is null`

Comment: check the id of tab(where we click). Use firebug or view source of page.

Comment: Here is how it shows in firebug, `<dl id="pane" class="tabs">
<dt class="panel1 open" style="cursor: pointer;">
<span>Movie Information</span>
</dt>
<dt class="panel2 closed" style="cursor: pointer;">
<span>Gallery</span>
</dt>
<dt class="panel3 closed" style="cursor: pointer;">
<span>Trailer</span>
</dt>
</dl>` But there is no id attribute in dt. I don't know what to do! What did I do wrong?

Comment: Then how to do it? any idea. I am stuck bcoz of this. Plz help.

Comment: Actually I don't know too much about mootools. I will search for it. Meanwhile you also search, how to fire event with class name of element in MooTools.

Answer (score 0):

I use following code,

```
<a id="showMyTab" href="javascript:void(0);">My Favourite Tab</a>

JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration("
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        $('showMyTab').addEvent('click', function(){
            $$('.tabs .myfavtab').fireEvent('click');
        });
    });
");
```

In your case changes will look like,

```
$$('.tabs .panel3').fireEvent('click');
```